# Can't resolve "TypeError: not a function" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to connect an Express app to mongodb using the node driver for mongodb.  For some reason, I keep getting a TypeError: mongodbconnect is not a function.  I think I've correctly exported/imported this function and don't think I have any circular references either.  I can't understand what's wrong with my code.

www.js (this is where the app starts with nodemon):

```
var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('myapp:server');
var http = require('http');

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '8085'); /*function normalizePort defined elsewhere in this file*/
app.set('port', port);

var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError); /*function onError defined elsewhere in this file*/
server.on('listening', onListening); /*function onListening defined elsewhere in this file*/
```

app.js

```
/*required body-parser, cookie-parser, cors, http-errors, express, morgan, path and Winston*/
var mongodbconnect = require('./mongodbconnect');
var contactUsRouter = require(path.join(__dirname, 'routes', 'contactUs'));

//connecting to MongoDB
mongodbconnect(function(err,databaseName){
  if (err) console.log(err)
  var app = express();
  app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.use(logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
  app.use(cors());
  app.use('/api/contactus', contactUsRouter);

  //error handler
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.status(500).send('Problem');
  });

  module.exports = app;
})
```

mongodbconnect.js

```
var assert = require('assert'); //used for MongoDB connection
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var url = "mongodb://userID:passwd@localhost:27017/databank?authSource=admin";
var mongoDB_Options = {
  poolSize: 100,
  keepAlive: true,
  keepAliveInitialDelay: 300000,
  reconnectInterval: 1000,
  reconnectTries: 10,
  autoReconnect: true,
  socketTimeoutMS: 360000,
  connectTimeoutMS: 30000
};
var dbName = 'bank';
function connectToMongoServer(callback){
  Mongoclient.connect(url, mongoDB_Options, function(err, client){
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log('Connected successfully to server');
    var db = client.db(dbName);
    return callback(err);
  });
};
module.exports = connectToMongoServer;
```

I would have expected this to code to allow me to connect to the MongoDB server, initiate my express app, and allow my front end Angular 7 app to perform CRUD operations in the MongoDB database.  Instead, I get this "mongodbconnect is not a function" error.  Can you please advise what's wrong about my code?  Please bear in mind that I'm fairly new to javascript, Node and Express.  So a simple explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Did you run the 'mongod.exe' before start the application. 'https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/'.....check this link

Comment: @DasunManathunga: I did not. I would have thought that if mongod wasn't stared before the application, the application would at least try to connect to mongodb and give an error that suggested that mongo server isn't running. Instead I got the error about mongodbconnect not being a function. Not sure I understand how the error I got instead is connected to mongod not being active. If I start mongod before the application, I get the following error instead: "app.set is not a function". I don't understand how to export "app" from app.js correctly, since it's inside mongodbconnect in app.js.

Answer (score 0):

The initialization of the module is wrong.

#### You deferred the act of setting `module.exports` in app.js

In app.js you defer the setting of `module.exports` until after the asynchronous callback of `mongodbconnect` completes.

You have the code `module.exports = app;` ***inside the callback*** that you passed to mongodbconnect, which doesn't get called before the module initialization is complete (the "require" of app.js).

By then, it's too late.  In www.js, `app` has already been assigned a value, and it's not the same object that you assign to `module.exports` in app.js.

Comment: that's the part I'm struggling with.  Any suggestions on how to modify the code?  Should I invoke mogodbconnect (with a callback) from www.js and include ```app.set('port', port)``` inside the callback?  If not, appreciate some help in making this work.